# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise in node_modules\snapdragon-util\index.js:282 rejection react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this issues in an android emulator while running react-android.
I have checked with npm ls snapdragon-util then it was shown paper dependency is snapdragon-utile

error below like this

DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit.

is it react-native project issue or package-issue?

Comment: There's an error that won't catch you in the code.